# What should the second to last dense layer be?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

When looking online at Keras CNN examples, I always see the last two layers being fully connected layers like..

```
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
```

I understand the last Dense layer and the fact that the number is 3 because in this specific case, that is the amount of possible classes to choose from.

What I don't understand is why the second to last Dense layer is 64. Sometimes it's 64, or 128 or 512.

My question is what does the 64 mean in `model.add(Dense(64))` and what determines this number?

Comment: Trial and error... empirical data... whims and fancies... you name it.

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO since it is not about keras coding, Try it on [cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It means a fully connected neural layer (NOT a CNN layer) with 64 nodes in it.

Answer (score 3):

64 is the number of neuron in that layer. Why 64? there are no "exact" rules for number of neuron in hidden layer. May be it is a result of tuning parameter, or it chosen because their machine can't run with 100 neuron, or something else.

When you create a neural network, number of neuron in a layer is one of many hyper-parameters you should tune to find the best result. And also the number of hidden layer (don't you ask why there are 1 fully connected hidden layers?) or activation function.

I've read from https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1097/105981: '*the optimal size of the hidden layer is usually between the size of the input and size of the output layers*', but in many cases that I've ever done, that's not happen